# Detect the same word in tokens ngram and remove them

Tags: r, quanteda

In a dfm how is it possible to detect in an ngram the same words i.e.

```
hello_hello, text_text
```

and remove them from the dfm?

Comment: For ngrams of any length, or just for bigrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a dfm in which your ngram elements are joined by `_`, then you can split them and determine which are the same.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.2

dfmat <- dfm(c("test1_test1", "test1_test2", "test2_test2_test2", "test2_other", "other"))

featsplit <- strsplit(featnames(dfmat), "_")
same <- sapply(featsplit, function(y) {
  length(y) >= 2 & # it's a compound (ngram)
    length(unique(y)) == 1 # all elements are the same
})

same
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You can then use this to make a selection for the elements of the dfm that are not the same:

```r
dfmat[, !same]
## Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 3 features (80.0% sparse).
##        features
## docs    test1_test2 test2_other other
##   text1           0           0     0
##   text2           1           0     0
##   text3           0           0     0
##   text4           0           1     0
##   text5           0           0     1
```

If your ngram concatenator is a different character, just substitute that for the `_`.