# Remove words from a dataframe which are the same in different place

Tags: r, quanteda

Having words in a dfm like this
library("quanteda")

### Package version: 2.1.2

```
dfmat <- dfm(c("hello_text","text_hello","test1_test2", "test2_test1", "test2_test2_test2", "test2_other", "other"))
```

which for example the tokens "hello_text" and "text_hello" are the same in different place. How is it possile to keep only one of this options?

Example output

```
dfmat <- dfm(c("hello_text","test1_test2",  "test2_test2_test2", "test2_other", "other"))
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65279365) solution example but it removes the same words

Comment: You want to remove the "text_hello"? Or convert them to "hello_text"? If they are tokens, then `tokens_remove()` is your best bet. If they are character vector here, then you can use `char_remove()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the strings at the underscore and sort them alphabetically, then use this list to identify duplicates and apply it to the original list:

```
words <- c("hello_text","text_hello","test1_test2", "test2_test1", "test2_test2_test2", "test2_other", "other")

words_sorted <- sapply(sapply(words, strsplit, "_"), sort)

words[!duplicated(words_sorted)]
```

Returns:

```
[1] "hello_text"        "test1_test2"       "test2_test2_test2" "test2_other"      
[5] "other"
```

Comment: is it possible to make it in the dfm format?

Comment: You could wrap the result in `quanteda::tokens`; i.e.  `quanteda::dfm(quanteda::tokens(words[!duplicated(words_sorted)]))`. Does this answer it?