# Make the same tokens which are in different place

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this:

```
words <- c("hello_text","text_hello","test1_test2", "test2_test1", "test2_test2_test2", "test2_other", "other")
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615236/14961922) it is possible to detect tokens which have the same words into different place and remove them.

```
words_sorted <- sapply(sapply(words, strsplit, "_"), sort)

words[!duplicated(words_sorted)]
```

How is it possible to find and just change them?

Example out put:

```
    c("hello_text","hello_text","test1_test2", "test1_test2", "test2_test2_test2", "test2_other", "other")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `sort` and `paste` the data -

```
sapply(strsplit(words, '_'), function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = '_'))

#[1] "hello_text"    "hello_text"       "test1_test2"    "test1_test2"      
#[5] "test2_test2_test2" "other_test2"       "other"
```